# Simple proof about induced $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\cal F$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and $A$ a subset of $\Omega$. Show that $\mathcal C=\{A\cap B:B\in\mathcal F\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $A$. Show that it is not a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$.

I do not understand how to prove that $\mathcal C$ is closed under complementation.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to show that $$A\setminus(A\cap B)=A\cap(\Omega\setminus B)$$ for any subset $B$ of $\Omega.$ Incidentally, you'll need to assume that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $\Omega$ to conclude that $\mathcal C$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ (why?).

---

**Edit**: It looks like the problem is arising from misleading notation. Given an arbitrary set $D,$ what is $D^c$? Well, it isn't the set of all objects that aren't in $D$--that turns out not to be a set at all! That notation *only* makes sense if we are working with subsets of *one particular set*. Let me provide an alternate phrasing that should make clearer what is necessary (and why the hint I gave above shows exactly what we want to show).

> A set of sets $\mathcal S$ is said to be a *$\sigma$-algebra of subsets of* (a set) $X$ if the following conditions hold:
>
> - Every element of $\mathcal S$ is a subset of $X$;
> - $X\in\mathcal S;$
> - for any countable subset $\mathcal E$ of $\mathcal S,$ we have $\bigcup\limits_{E\in\mathcal E}E\in\mathcal S;$
> - for any $E\in\mathcal S,$ we have $X\setminus E\in\mathcal S.$

This last condition is the one you've been having trouble with. The notation I use makes it clearer *exactly* the set in which we're taking relative complements.

Since $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$, then $\Omega\setminus B\in\mathcal F$ whenever $B\in\mathcal F.$ In order to show that $\mathcal C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $A,$ we must show that $A\setminus D\in\mathcal C$ whenever $D\in\mathcal C$. Does that clear up your confusion?

Comment: this is clear. but C is the set of all intersections of A with a sigma algebra in Ω. So I need to show that for each C_i∈ C its complement is in C. Then if C_i=A∩B for some B∈F, (C_i)^c=(A∩B)^c should be written as the intersection of A with an element of the sigma algebra. How can I do?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to make it clearer what's going on. Let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly the problem I was facing! Using your notation the proof comes naturally end easily. :)

Comment: You are very welcome! Incidentally, for future reference, after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). Welcome to Math.SE!